# generate combinations of Cojoint in Rstudio

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is a way to generate combinations as I will show below in Rstudio for a cojoint

The exercise says the following: Suppose you are purchasing a stove for your home. Given the options shown below, which option would you buy based on the brands and prices shown?
If no product is acceptable to you, please select none of the above. 9 individuals will be displayed per screen, in a total of 27 different combinations of the 9

Brand: ACROS Price: Q 2299

Brand: ACROS Price: Q 1599

Brand: GRS Price: Q 2299

Brand: GRS Price: Q 2069.1

Brand: GRS Price: Q 1169.1

Brand: GRS Price: Q 2699

Brand: GRS Price: Q 1039.2

Brand: MABE Price: Q 2299

Brand: MABE Price: Q 1499

Brand: MABE Price: Q 2799

Brand: WHIRPOOL Price: Q 2899

I did the exercise with an Excel package and the result is the following:

[image]

Is it possible to obtain such a combination in R?

Comment: Could someone explain what guidelines I didn't follow to make me get a bad grade?

Comment: When you were posting your question, there was a tag warning: *Ensure your R question contains: 1. Usable sample data (not just pictures) such as with dput function.  2. The code that isn't working (including the errors, unexpected results, etc.) 3. Your desired output 4. For more information, refer to [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406)*. Read the linked article, that explains it. Cheers :)

Comment: Hello, the data is the 11 brands that I provide with prices, nothing more, I have not tried to code because I don't know if there is a way, it is not clear at all.

Comment: It's possible. You can use `geom_tile()` along with `geom_text()` or `geom_label()` in ggplot2 package. You have 11 options and are showing 9 per row, if you want to randomly select data for each row (9 out of 11) you can use `sample()` function. Now you can try something and then if you ran into issues, either edit this post or post a new question (editing is better to avoid getting a question ban; read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)). + Read the article in my last comment for your benefit